# How to include all input value from HTML into req.body: Node.js (Express)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to get a value of checkbox, "1" in the following html, through req.body. However, in the req.body, username and password values are only included (passwordConfirm is not included as well).

How can I include the values of passwordConfirm and checkbox in req.body?Or is there another way to get the value of checkbox without req.body?

```
<form action="/register" method="POST">
        
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
    
    
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
    
    
        <label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm"><br><br>
    
    
        <label>?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1"><br><br>
    
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

index.js

```
const controller = require("controller.js");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/register", controller.newUser);
```

controller.js

```
function newUser(req, res){
     console.log(req.body.checkbox);//returns undefined
}

module.exports =. {
     newUser
}
```

I tried putting <script> in html to include a function that returns the value of checkbox accessing document object and called the function in a server-side js file, but it did not work (server-side js cannot call the function in client-side js).

Comment: If the checkbox does not be checked, you cannot get it on the server side.

Comment: @TheKNVB I submit the form with checkbox as checked, but did not contain in req.body

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following server-side code, it works.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post("/register",  express.json(),(req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works in that implementation. However, when controller passed as parameter in app.post console out the req.body, it returns username and password only.

Comment: Which version node.js you are using? My node js (16.13.0) report that the syntax of controller.js is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Qustion 1.

```
var chck=req.body.checkbox;
    if(chck===undefined){chck=false}else(chck=true);
```

Because checked one returns to your server true!! non checked -- undefined.

Q2. All input form values to a server:

```
 const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
  const myArray = req.body.myArray;
  // Now myArray contains an array of values: ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"]
  // You can process this array as needed
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Your contact.html:

```
<form method="post" action="/your-server-endpoint">
  <input type="text" name="myArray[]" value="Value 1">
  <input type="text" name="myArray[]" value="Value 2">
  <input type="hidden" name="myArray[]" value="Value 3">
  <!-- Add more inputs as needed -->
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

/** Decode Form URL Encoded data */
app.use(express.urlencoded());

/** Show page with a form */
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`<form method="POST" action="/">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
  <input type="submit">
</form>`);
});

/** Process POST request */
app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});

/** Run the app */
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You should always add an explanation to code when you're answering and not just a snippet, to help others understand what it does and why it solves the given problem.